# How to add a unique identifier in JQuery AJAX File Upload?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using  the following code that works fine in an asp.net mvc app,

In the header part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#fileupload').fileupload({
            dataType: 'json',
            url: '@Url.Action("UploadFile", "Payment")',
            autoUpload: true,
            done: function (e, data) {
                $('.file_name').html(data.result.name);
                $('.file_type').html(data.result.type);
                $('.file_size').html(data.result.size);
            }
        }).on('fileuploadprogressall', function (e, data) {
            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
            $('.progress .progress-bar').css('width', progress + '%');
        });
    });
</script>
```

in body use section:

```
    <span>
        <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button" style="width: 200px; float: left;">
            <span>Certificate: </span>
            <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
        </span>
    </span>
```

Problem is that, there are going to be number of use sites in the body, each for an object with a different Identity, so when the action on server responds to file upload, it needs to also get an extra parameter for the id of the object:

```
    <span>
        <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button" style="width: 200px; float: left;">
            <span>Certificate for Object ID=100: </span>
            <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
        </span>
    </span>  
    <span>
        <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button" style="width: 200px; float: left;">
            <span>Certificate for Object ID=101: </span>
            <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
        </span>
    </span>  
    <span>
        <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button" style="width: 200px; float: left;">
            <span>Certificate for Object ID=102: </span>
            <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
        </span>
    </span>
```

How can I add an additional Object Id parameter to be posted to server ?

Here is the Action on the Payment Controller code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ContentResult UploadFile()
    {
        var r = new List<UploadFilesResult>();

        foreach (string file in Request.Files)
        {
            HttpPostedFileBase hpf = Request.Files[file] as HttpPostedFileBase;
            if (hpf.ContentLength == 0)
                continue;

            string savedFileName = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data"), Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName));
            hpf.SaveAs(savedFileName);

            r.Add(new UploadFilesResult()
            {
                Name = hpf.FileName,
                Length = hpf.ContentLength,
                Type = hpf.ContentType
            });
        }
        return Content("{\"name\":\"" + r[0].Name + "\",\"type\":\"" + r[0].Type + "\",\"size\":\"" + string.Format("{0} bytes", r[0].Length) + "\"}", "application/json");
    }
```

Comment: use class instead and in jquery selector : ``$('.fileupload')``

Comment: @EhsanSajjad : Thank you, how do I pass the extra id parameter ?

Comment: 3 elements with `id="fileupload"` is invalid html (and only the first would work anyway). Could you just give them different names? - `name="files-100[]"`, `name="files-101[]"`

Comment: @StephenMuecke : Yep, sure, just one question, how does that gets passes as a variable to server?

Comment: Its not a variable - its just means you can access them as `Request.Files[files-100]` etc, but I'm not sure if that would meet you needs - I'm a little unsure of what you are trying to do

Comment: @StephenMuecke : I am trying to distinguish which one of the file upload controls posted the file.

Comment: @StephenMuecke :  That actually worked! I assumed because it is an AJAX call only the file and the JSON payload get sent to server, I was mistaken.

Comment: The `name` attribute of a control is always sent along with the value. But not sure how flexible this will be for you if you have varying numbers of `ID`'s. I'm not familiar with the jquery plugin your using and hence if there might be a better way.

Comment: @StephenMuecke : What I have is pretty much this the sample at the end of this article : http://davidsonsousa.net/en/post/how-to-upload-a-file-using-mvc-3-and-ajax . The only difference is that I am trying to have each file upload control associated with a specific ID, in my case the ID is the ID of item being viewed on the screen,

Comment: @Arjang, Looking at the [documentation](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/How-to-submit-additional-form-data), you should be able to use `$('#fileupload1').fileupload({ formData: { id: 100 }, url: '@Url.Action("UploadFile", "Payment")', ...});` and include `int id` as a parameter in `public ContentResult UploadFile(int id) { ..}` - you would need to give each element a unique `id` so you can set `formData: { id: ### }`

Comment: @StephenMuecke : If I give each element a unique Id, it seems the problem of all the upload controls responding to the same upload complete and progress events would also go away, It means attaching the a different fileupload to each one of the elements, instead of varying a parameter to call it.

Comment: You should also change your method to `public JsonResult UploadFile(int id)` and use `return Json(new { name = r[0].Name, type = r[0].Type, etc })` and access it with `data.name` etc.

Comment: @StephenMuecke : Thank you Stephen, Can you please modify(/fork?) the project here : https://github.com/ArjangAssadi/JQueryFileUploadMVC4 .I cant understand what you are telling me to do, That is a working version on github, please modify it and let me know , I can look up the differences between the projects. I am new to using GitHub, MVC, and JQuery, sorry. Please don't hesitate to guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Try class as identifier instead of using id

Comment: Thank you,  Ehsan Sajjad also suggested that but how do I pass the one extra parameter?